# Upgrading PHP on MediaTemple Server

Tags: php, linux, mediatemple

I followed the instructions from http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(dv):Upgrade_software_with_YUM

But I'm having some weirdness happen. My linux knowledge is very limited, so I have a feeling it's something simple.

Basically when I do `php -v` on my server I get

```
PHP 5.3.10 (cli) (built: Feb  3 2012 08:08:52)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

But my web server is still running an older version of php. (5.1.4 to be exact).

I tried `/etc/httpd restart` but the web server still says 5.1.4.

How do I get my web server to run the correct version? Do I need to uninstall it somewhere?

Comment: 5.3.3 is in the base repo. Is there a specific reason why you needed 5.3.10?

Comment: No, but on my server it is running 5.1 and i just need it at 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is opening up a support request, or try contacting us via support chat or Twitter. We should be able to guide you through fixing the problem. I need to see the actual account to see what's going on.